# Mpdf don't display image in report

Tags: php

if (!empty($row['image_upload'])) {

```
        $imagePath = 'e-dados/raifatin/' . $row['image_upload']; 
         
        
        if (file_exists($fullImagePath)) {
             
            $html .= '<td><img src="' . $imagePath . '" style="width: 100px; height: auto;"></td>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<td>No Image Found at: ' . $fullImagePath . '</td>';
        }
    } else {
        $html .= '<td>No Image Available</td>';
    }
```

IS there any one can fix my issue?

Comment: (1) `$fullImagePath` is not the same as `$imagePath` (2) Please edit your question so that it can properly display the code (did you view your question after posting it ?)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($row['image_upload'])) {
    $imagePath = 'e-dados/raifatin/' . $row['image_upload']; 

    if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
        $html .= '<td><img src="' . $imagePath . '" style="width: 100px; height: auto;"></td>';
    } else {
        $html .= '<td>No Image Found at: ' . $imagePath . '</td>';
    }
} else {
    $html .= '<td>No Image Available</td>';
}
```

I've replaced $fullImagePath with $imagePath in the file_exists() check, as it seems like $imagePath is the correct variable holding the path to the image file. Make sure that the path is correct and points to the location where your images are stored.